# Elasticsearch geo_bounding_box failed to derive xcontent

Tags: elasticsearch, bounding-box

I have stored a few documents in Elasticsearch, each of which contains an array of coordinates to draw a line on Google Maps. On these documents I want to do a Geo Bounding Box Query to know which ones are relevant to where the user is looking on the map.
When I attempt this I get the error "Failed to derive xcontent".

This is an example of how one of the documents look (can contain hundreds of coordinates):

```
{
    "type" : "Feature",
    "properties" : {
      "Type" : "Path",
      "Name" : "An example line"
    },
    "geometry" : {
      "type" : "LineString",
      "coordinates" : [ [ 14.998659698781326, 59.83282967919488 ], [ 14.998221382378132, 59.832346163020866 ], [ 14.997889000000002, 59.83210100000001 ], [ 14.997201215918253, 59.83165390720879 ], [ 14.996313, 59.83200200000001 ] ]
    }
}
```

This is the query I am running using curl (beautified for readability, otherwise in one line without spaces):

```
curl.exe http://11.11.111.111:9200/map/path/_search?pretty -d'
{
    "query": {
        "geo_bounding_box": {
            "location": {
                "top_left": {
                    "lat": 60.50,
                    "lon": 14.30
                },
                "bottom_right": {
                    "lat": 59.86,
                    "lon": 16.06
                }
            }
        }
    }
}'
```

This is the respone from the above query:

```
{
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [ {
      "type" : "parse_exception",
      "reason" : "Failed to derive xcontent"
    } ],
    "type" : "search_phase_execution_exception",
    "reason" : "all shards failed",
    "phase" : "query",
    "grouped" : true,
    "failed_shards" : [ {
      "shard" : 0,
      "index" : "map",
      "node" : "ye2EayFlRFCM6xGWjzcfwQ",
      "reason" : {
        "type" : "parse_exception",
        "reason" : "Failed to derive xcontent"
      }
    } ]
  },
  "status" : 400
}
```

And this is the log found in Elasticsearch:

```
[2016-07-31 10:23:10,268][DEBUG][action.search            ] [one] [map][2], node[ye2EayFlRFCM6xGWjzcfwQ], [P], v[2], s[STARTED], a[id=Ptvmzu-2R6WHH89BLifz6g]: Failed to execute [org.elasticsearch.action.search.SearchRequest@866697a] lastShard [true]
RemoteTransportException[[one][10.3.0.4:9300][indices:data/read/search[phase/query]]]; nested: SearchParseException[failed to parse search source [_na_]]; nested: ElasticsearchParseException[Failed to derive xcontent];
Caused by: SearchParseException[failed to parse search source [_na_]]; nested: ElasticsearchParseException[Failed to derive xcontent];
        at org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService.parseSource(SearchService.java:855)
        at org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService.createContext(SearchService.java:654)
        at org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService.createAndPutContext(SearchService.java:620)
        at org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService.executeQueryPhase(SearchService.java:371)
        at org.elasticsearch.search.action.SearchServiceTransportAction$SearchQueryTransportHandler.messageReceived(SearchServiceTransportAction.java:368)
        at org.elasticsearch.search.action.SearchServiceTransportAction$SearchQueryTransportHandler.messageReceived(SearchServiceTransportAction.java:365)
        at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportRequestHandler.messageReceived(TransportRequestHandler.java:33)
        at org.elasticsearch.transport.RequestHandlerRegistry.processMessageReceived(RequestHandlerRegistry.java:75)
        at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService$4.doRun(TransportService.java:376)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.AbstractRunnable.run(AbstractRunnable.java:37)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: ElasticsearchParseException[Failed to derive xcontent]
        at org.elasticsearch.common.xcontent.XContentFactory.xContent(XContentFactory.java:240)
        at org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService.parseSource(SearchService.java:824)
```

The JSON itself validates as correct.Other queries work correctly, I can get a specific one by ID and retrieve all as well. Only this query is giving me some trouble.

I have tried a query using filters as on the  [documentations](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-geo-bounding-box-query.html) page but that did not work either, giving the same error as the one I mentioned above.
I am using Elasticsearch 2.3.1 on Linux.

What is needed to make this query work? What does the error "Failed to derive xcontent" mean in this case and how can I solve it?

Comment: Not related to the issue you're facing, but `geo_bounding_box` only works against geo points, not geo shapes.

Comment: The documentation does say "The filter can work with multiple locations / points per document. Once a single location / point matches the filter, the document will be included in the filter".
A linestring is essentially a a bunch of points through which a line is drawn, or am I misinterpreting?

Comment: I believe you're misinterpreting. You can have an array of points, which is different from a line.

Comment: In that case, do you know what I should be using instead to perform this query?

Comment: [`geo_shape`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.3/query-dsl-geo-shape-query.html) is the more flexible geo query/filter meant to be used with the `geo_shape` data type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case some one else has the same problem, here's the solution I found. 
In the curl query I wrote -d'[JSON]' and simply removing the ' around the [JSON] did the trick. Now Elasticsearch can read the query.
I have moved on to experimenting with [geo_shape](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-geo-shape-query.html) query instead as pickypg suggested.

```
CORRECT: -d [JSON] 
INCORRECT: -d '[JSON]'
```